# How to evaluate the following Product?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, products, telescopic-series

so I have the following product to evaluate :
$$P_{n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} u_{k}$$
Where : $u_k = e^{w_n}$
All what I know about $u_k$ is that
$$
u_{n}=\frac{n+2}{n+1}
$$
So we'll have the following :
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_{n}=e^{w_{n}} \Leftrightarrow w_{n} &=\ln \left(u_{n}\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow w_{n} &=\ln \left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right) \\
&=\ln (n+2)-\ln (n+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
And I transformed the product to the following :
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{n} &=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} u_{k} \\
&=e^{w_{0}} \times e^{w_{1}} \times \cdots \times e^{w_{n-1}} \\
&=e^{w_{0}+w_{1}+\cdots+w_{n-1}} \\
\ln \left(P_{n}\right) &=w_{0}+w_{1} \ldots + w_{n-1} \\
&=(\ln 2-\ln 1)+(\ln 3-\ln 2)+\ldots+( \ln (n+1)-\ln (n))
\end{aligned}
$$
And yeah from here I got kind confused because of the elimination of terms, can someone guide me ?
And if someone is interested it's an exercise from a Moroccan exam, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the $e^{w_n}$ part of the problem statement?$\require{cancel}$ Otherwise why not to do just $P_{n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k+2}{k+1}=\frac{\cancel{2}}{1}\frac{\cancel{3}}{\cancel{2}}\cdots \frac{n+1}{\cancel{n}}=n+1$ ?

Comment: @Sil yes indeed I'm obligated to use $e$ and $\ln$ and thank youfor the remark !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln (2)$ cancels with the $-\ln (2)$ and $\ln (3)$ cancels with the $-\ln (3)$ and so on leaving
$\ln (n+1) -\ln (1)$

edit:
unless you have to use $e$ and $ln$ then

$$P_n = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}u_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k+2}{k+1}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2}{1}\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}.....\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n+1}{n}$$
and cancelling diagonly i.e. 2 with $\frac{1}{2}$ and so give $P_n = n+1$

Is that clear?

Comment: Are my steps correct ?

Comment: yes your steps are correct but I'm not sure why you use $e$ and $\ln$